# How to show up eslint syntax hinting for .eslintrc.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, nestjs, eslint

When i config eslint,i found **syntax hinting** works in .eslintrc.json otherwise **.eslintrc.js**.
Anyone encountered this problem?Is there any way to fix it?
Or i just write the config at .json and mv it to the .js?
What is the solution?

I asked gpt4 and add the code at gg(vim),but it didn't work.

```
/**
 * @type {import("eslint").Linter.Config}
 */
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been using this in my `.eslintrc.js` file:

```js
// @ts-check
/**
 * @type {import('eslint').Linter.Config}
 */
module.exports = {}
```

Comment: Thank you. The introduction of JSDoc has provided hints for the core properties of the ESLint configuration, but the syntax hints for their nested properties are still missing.

Comment: yeah. Due to the dynamic nature of few nested properties, there's no way to `eslint` package to know the typings, right?